# Saving file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm new to programming in C#. I want to create and download an `xml` file. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization) artical on creating the xml. I followed it and it works perfect. But I can't figure out how to save the file to my computer. I think it has to be inplemented someware here:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Read and write purchase orders.
    Test t = new Test();
    t.CreatePO("po.xml");
    //I think here the file is ready to dowload
    t.ReadPO("po.xml");
}
```

As for the `t.CreatePO("po.xml");` function I have exactly whats in the artical.
From the artical I took the last example.
The 'file' is created by a `StreamWriter`. Then it converts an object to a XML by using `Serialize`.

Any step in the right direction will help!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: @TaW I'm using the `.net` framework. I also added the Tag in the question.

Comment: @Tim567 I believe he means that the information your tag can provide is not detailed enough. It will be better if you give more information, like `WinForm`, `ASP .Net Api`, etc. As for your question, to download a file, you can 1) directly download the file from server. Or 2) get the content from serve then write it into a local file.

Comment: I guess the crucial questions are: (1) What does ``t.CreatePO("po.xml")`` do? Looks like it creates a file ``po.xml`` but where does it create the file? (2) What do you mean by 'download?'

Comment: @dumetrulo For your point one please look at the artical I refest to in the question. for your point 2: I want to save the `xml` as a file on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, you want to save the file to your computer.

You could try the following code to get it.

```
// Creates an instance of the XmlSerializer class;
// specifies the type of object to serialize.
XmlSerializer serializer =
new XmlSerializer(typeof(PurchaseOrder));
//We can use absolute paths to store it anywhere on the computer
string xmlPath = @"D:\Task\";           
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(xmlPath,filename));
PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works! Only had to add `writer.Write(xmlString);` and there it is! Thanks.